# How do I group and map identical column values to new column with corresponding values for posts

Tags: mysql, database-schema, wordpress, database-migration

I currently am using the following code to get a list of posts, showing post_name, post_content and post_id, where there is a custom field (meta_key) used named MediaLink.

```
 SELECT wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.ID 
 FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
 WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
 AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = "MediaLink"
```

Here is a visual example of my current table from that query:

post_name   |  post_content | post_id |

---

```
Name 1         Content 1        1
Name 2         Content 2        2
```

I would like to have the following table:

post_name   |  post_content | post_id | Artist |   Producer

---

```
Name 1         Content 1        1      Madonna    Philip    
Name 2         Content 2        2      Prince     Jack
```

The problem is that Artist & Producer is currently in the wp_postmeta table as :

```
meta_key | meta_value | post_id | meta_id |
___________________________________________
Artist     Madonna         1         1
Artist     Prince          2         2
Producer   Philip          1         3
Producer   Jack            2         4
```

What do I add to my initial query to to first query to accomplish this?

I want to show the producer and Artist column for post rows that both do and don't have the Artist and Producer fields filled out yet.

This way I can export this data to CSV with PhpMyAdmin and update thousands of posts, affecting all the fields I need per post in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick (I can't test properly without your data, so let me know if you get any weird results):

```
 SELECT p.post_name,
        p.post_content,
        p.ID,
        art.meta_value as artist,
        prd.meta_value as producer
 FROM wp_posts p
      JOIN wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
      LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta art on p.ID = art.post_id and art.meta_key = 'Artist' 
      LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta prd on p.ID = prd.post_id and prd.meta_key = 'Producer' 
WHERE pm.meta_key = "MediaLink"
```

By way of explanation, you can use a table several times in a query if you give it an alias.  I've used `pm`, `art`, and `prd` to reference `wp_postmeta` under different conditions.

I changed your syntax to ANSI join syntax, as I find it easier to see what's going on: the join conditions are separate from the criteria (though there's a grey area with the Artist and Producer conditions - see below).

Since you said

> I want to show the producer and Artist column for post rows that both
>   do and don't have the Artist and Producer fields filled out yet.

I made the joins `LEFT JOIN`s, which will always return the row from the left table, add `NULL` from the right table if the row doesn't exist.  I put the Artist / Producer in the join condition, not the `WHERE` clause because it's evaluated after the join and you'd lose those `NULL` records.

Comment: This is correct! Thank you. My next step is to click export in PhpMyAdmin after I run the query and the the correct results, use the csv formart, edit in excel and import back to my main database table? (which the breadcrumb says it was exported from)